# Is there a way to fix the audio sync on the Aquaris M10 Ubuntu Edition?

Tags: sound, ubuntu-touch, aquaris

I just got an Aquaris M10 Ubuntu Edition FHD to replace my very old Dell Ubuntu netbook. The first thing I've noticed is that the video and audio are way out of sync whenever playing a Youtube or Vimeo video. I've read in other places that other people are also having this problem with the Aquaris. Is there a way to rectify this?

Comment: I don't seem to have this problem have you updated to the latest version ?

Comment: Yes the updates page says "software is up to date"

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue now.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1574729